# i cannot use the router.post method in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, .post

i try to use a post request in my node.js application but for some reason that i cannot find it is not working. Perhaps you can help me with this issue

below you can find my report.js and my report.ejs files:

report.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { Pool, Client } = require("pg");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
/* GET home page. */

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : false }));

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('report', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/top', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.todo + " is added to top of the list.");
  res.redirect('/');
});

router.post('/bottom', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.todo + " is added to bottom of the list.");
  res.json({ status: 'success' });
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

report.ejs file:

```
  <body>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>To Do:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="todo">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" formaction="/top"  method="POST">Add to Top</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" formaction="/bottom"  method="POST">Add to Bottom</button>
  </form>
    <script src="/javascripts/reportjs.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and i get the error message for both of the buttons:

```
GET /report 304 10.606 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/report.css 304 2.708 ms - -
GET /javascripts/reportjs.js 304 0.739 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/headder.css 304 1.229 ms - -
GET /bottom?todo=asdasd 404 2.253 ms - 145

Cannot GET /bottom
```

i dont understand why the application is using a GET method when i use a POST method

Comment: this should not have anything to do with your node.js code, the issue is on the client side.

Comment: ok :) but you know how to check what the issue is on the client side? is the browser a problem in this case? it should not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `method` attribute should be on the `<form>` tag, not the `<button>` tag. The default method is `GET` so that's what the form is doing.  Try this:

```
<form method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>To Do:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="todo">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" formaction="/report/top">Add to Top</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" formaction="/report/bottom">Add to Bottom</button>
</form>
```

Or you could use `formmethod` on the `<button>` tag like this:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>To Do:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="todo">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" formaction="/report/top" formmethod="POST"">Add to Top</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" formaction="/report/bottom" formmethod="POST">Add to Bottom</button>
</form>
```

Since both buttons use `POST` it's nicer to put it on the `<form>` tag and avoid repetition, in my opinion.

The `formaction` should start with `/report/top` or `/report/bottom` as the current location from the page will be within `/report` and relative to that. If you use just `/top` or `/bottom` it loses context from the `/report` location.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. i did that but get now Cannot POST /top

Comment: try adding this to before your first `router.get` in the server to see if your request is making it to your router: `router.use((req,res,next)=>{console.log(">>>",req.method,req.url,req.body); return next();});`

Comment: done, i get: `>>> GET / {}
GET /report 304 13.904 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/report.css 304 1.645 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/headder.css 304 1.096 ms - -
GET /javascripts/reportjs.js 304 0.937 ms - -
POST /top 404 19.882 ms - 143`

Comment: from your output the ">>>" only happened once (for url "/") and the others didn't make it in

Comment: thanks but it still did not make it `>>> GET / {}
GET /report 304 3.625 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/report.css 304 0.598 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/headder.css 304 1.222 ms - -
GET /javascripts/reportjs.js 304 1.043 ms - -
POST /http://localhost:8080/top 404 0.896 ms - 165` the error is now `Cannot POST /http://localhost:8080/top`

Comment: where are those other console lines being printed from?

Comment: it is from the console of VS Code

Comment: so those are server side messages?

Comment: the fact that no more messages start with ">>>" means they're not getting to your router and failing before that. Is your router the main entry point to the server or is there a parent router that "uses" it?

Comment: is it possible that your `formaction` needs to be `/report/top` and `/report/bottom` to get to this router?

Comment: for the report.ejs the main router is report.js

Comment: pfff, thanks...that did it, but it should be possible to use only the /top or not?

Comment: I added to my answer to attempt an explanation of why you need to add `/report/`. Please accept the answer if you're happy :)